# How to return a sum() from a contained Table?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a custom finder method in my `Matches` table which contains some other tables and I would like to return the summed value for one of my contained fields.

So far I have the following.

```php
/**
 * Custom finder to find the latest matches played
 *
 * @param Query $query
 * @param array $options
 * @return $this
 */
    public function findLatestMatches(Query $query, array $options) {
        return $query->contain([
                'Venues' => function ($q) {
                    return $q->select(['id', 'name', 'location']);
                },
                'Formats' => function ($q) {
                    return $q->select(['id', 'name']);
                },
                'Teams' => [
                    'Clubs' => function ($q) {
                        return $q->select(['id', 'image', 'image_dir']);
                    }
                ],
                'Innings' => [
                    'InningsTypes',
                    'Batsmen' => function ($q) {
                        /* @var \Cake\ORM\Query $q */
                        return $q->select(['totalRuns' => $q->func()->sum('runs')]);
                    },
                    'Bowlers',
                    'Wickets' => function ($q) {
                        /* @var \Cake\ORM\Query $q */
                        return $q->select(['totalWickets' => $q->func()->count('id')]);
                    }
                ]
            ])
            ->order(['when_played' => 'DESC']);
    }
```

This code will execute fine and produce no errors. Also checking the SQL tab in DebugKit shows the sql as having been executed.

```sql
SELECT (SUM(runs)) AS `totalRuns` FROM batsmen Batsmen WHERE Batsmen.innings_id in ('841fce60-0178-450f-99e8-ad1670f5c84f','93daddf5-256b-4420-b636-0db626baae72','b398d1a0-2c7d-41f7-b2c3-8ea00ddfcece','f949bb45-3d8b-46f5-8967-cc1340a9c1e7')
```

However the data isn't available in any of the returned entities. Where can I find my aggregated data?

Comment: Can't test it right now, so I'll leave it as a comment, try adding the foreign key to the select fieldlists. Aside from that, I think you'll have to reformat the data in case this works at all, and maybe you should consider using [**counter caches**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html) instead.

Comment: I am currently just returning the whole data and using the collection methods for aggregation, but I would rather do it in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since done a bit of refactoring with this and moved the Bowlers wickets out into their own custom finder, to use in this finder.

Here is how I've approached my Bowlers custom finder.

```php
public function findBowlersWickets(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->contain([
        'Innings' => [
            'Wickets' => [
                'PlayerBowledWicket',
            ]
        ]
    ])
        ->select(['totalWickets' => $query->func()->count('*')])
        ->matching('Innings.Wickets.PlayerBowledWicket', function ($q) {
            return $q->where([
                'AND' => [
                    'Wickets.bowler_player_id = Bowlers.player_id',
                    'Wickets.innings_id = Innings.id'
                ]
            ]);
        })
        ->group(['Innings.id', 'Bowlers.player_id'])
        ->order(['totalWickets' => 'DESC'])
        ->autoFields(true);
}
```